# XmlPullParser: get/reconstruct raw XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xmlpullparser

I am tied to use the XmlPullParser (since we use the Smack XMPP library). 
But it is very inconvenient to parse XML with it and put the read values into beans (at least if an XSD is given). In contrast, JAXB would be so much easier to work with.

Also for serialization it is an "old-fashioned and error prone approach" to concatenate the strings manually. (see the motivation of http://babbler-xmpp.blogspot.co.at/2014_01_01_archive.html which also summarizes the cons).

But to use JAXB for deserialization, I have to get the raw XML-String.
Of course, one way would be to reconstruct the whole XML-String using the XmlPullParser's parsing-methods (like `getName()`, `getText()`, `getAttributes()`, ...). But I would like to avoid this.

So is it possible to get the whole raw XML-String of a specific tag (e.g. where the XmlPullParser is currently pointing to)? Or does anyone know some utility which reconstructs the XML of an XmlPullParser instance?

Comment: You are passing the XmkPullParser some Reader? Why not simply read everything twice? And: if you want to use JAXB for creating the POJO hieratchy: what is the purpose of pull-parsing the XML?

Comment: The problem is, that I don't have access to the Reader which represents the raw XML-stream. There is only the XmlPullParser passed from the framework (Smack) to my custom extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that there is no other way to get the raw XML-string, I decided to reconstruct it using the XmlPullParser's parsing-methods (as described in the question above).

Just in case anyone needs it: In a first draft, the code looks like this

```
int eventType = parser.getEventType(); 
String extensionElementName = parser.getName();
StringBuilder extensionBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String element = "";

while(!(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(extensionElementName))) {
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(element)) {
        // this is for elements which are closed immediately like the following example: <sample />
        // otherwise, this line would be added twice
    } else {
        extensionBuilder.append(parser.getText());
    }

    element = parser.getText();
    eventType = parser.next();
}

// append closing element
if(!parser.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(element)) 
    extensionBuilder.append(parser.getText());
```